# How to get Stamen background with political boundaries

Tags: background, mapping, layer, ggmap, stamen-maps

I once made a background map with political boundaries as follows:

`myMap = get_stamenmap(bbox = myLocation, zoom = 4, maptype = "terrain-background")`

and all was right with the world.

Now I need to recreate the map but 'get_stamenmap' has depreciated. Now I can use:

```
myMap = get_stadiamap(bbox = myLocation, zoom = 4, maptype = "stamen_terrain_background")
```

to get a backgroud map with no political borders. And I can use

```
myMapLines = get_stadiamap(bbox = myLocation, zoom = 4, maptype = "stamen_terrain_lines")
```

to get a map of political borders with no background. But I cannot figure how how to combine the two.

```
myMap1 \<- ggmap(myMap) + ggmap(myMapLines)
```

does not work. How do I put Humpty Dumpty back together?